# Long running job with Timer

Tags: timer-jobs, splongoperation

Can we use Timer Jobs to execute the processes that can take more than **30 mins**?

Is there any chance of timer job getting timeout during the long operation?

If Timer job is not the one then are there any better options for me? Someone suggested to create a Windows Service but I am looking for a SharePoint based solution.

Appreciate any help/suggestions from the community

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Timer jobs are **absolutely the right way** to execute long-running operations within a SharePoint environment.

There are also "standard" timer jobs that under some circumstances take hours to complete, especially on larger environments.